# Creating a popup when hovering a line in Mapbox

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a custom line in mapbox that displays a popup when you click it, how can I make it so it shows only when you hover it ? I changed from "click" to "mouseenter" but it did not closed the popup. What needs changing so when I hover over this line it shows the popup and then it closes when leaving the line/popup?

Here is a jsfiddle example :

JS

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = '';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
        center:  [-0.066985, 51.503363],
        zoom: 9
    });

map.on('load', function() {
        map.addSource('routeThree', {
            'type': 'geojson',
            'data': {
                'type': 'Feature',
                'properties': {},
                'geometry': {
                    'type': 'LineString',
                    'coordinates': [
                        [-0.066985, 51.503363],
                        [-3.550610, 40.390555 ],
                        [-77.140217, 38.801481],
                        [-118.175979, 34.008447]
                    ]
                }
            }
        });
        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'routeThree',
            'type': 'line',
            'source': 'routeThree',
            'layout': {
                'line-join': 'round',
                'line-cap': 'round'
            },
            'paint': {
                'line-color': '#04A5BD',
                'line-width': 8
            }
        });
   map.on('click', 'routeThree', function(e) {
            new mapboxgl.Popup()
            .setLngLat(e.lngLat)
            .setHTML("<h2>This is the third line that will explain something</h2>")
            .addTo(map);
         
         });
     
   
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

You'd need to add the closing as part of a `mouseleave` event

```
map.on('mouseleave', 'routeThree', function() {
  popup.remove();
});
```

---

Note that this assumes a template `popup` var *above* function scope to get accessed, i.e.

```
var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
  <options>
});
```

See the [official example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/popup-on-hover/) for more on the general usage.